# Android emulator is not launching

Tags: android, emulation

I am using Android SDK tools version 21.0.1 and eclipse helios.
Problem is that i am not able to launch the emulator.

after installing eclipse i created a new avd named 'emulator1',i get the small window of "Starting emulator for AVD 'emulator1'"

but nothing loads.i have waited upto 12 hours ,still nothing.

only process that runs in task manager is adb.exe. i tried killing it and starting it again but in vain.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Update your eclipse to Helios 3.6.2 and above. and try using latest android sdk and adt.

Here is the link to use [proper versions of tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) under **system requirement** section that works with your current sdk.

Update your jdk too.

Let us know after updating if you still encounter the same problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response....I have a pirated version of Windows that was why the emulator wasn't working. Extremely sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0):

restart eclipse and when you launch the emulator that time it takes lots of cpu memory so close the other tabs like browsers.

All things are depend on your machine configuration and speed so on that basis you have to wait and also check cpu memory when emulator is launching then you will get how to manage with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.. Extremely sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android in virtual box instead of an emulator which has so many issues. Explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29638854/1987258