# Android Emulator not launching in Windows7, Android Studio 1.1, API22

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, emulation

I have been able to successfully launch emulator in past. But lately I switched to Android Studio 1.1 and emulator does not launch at all, either with API21 or 22. In my "Run" Window I do get the message that "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode". but beyond that nothing appears on the screen. I am on Windows 7 , enterprise. Please help...

Vikas

Answer (score 0):

You are not the first person who haves problems with Android Emulators. They are slow, do not work in some situations and have multiple other issues. An alternative is running Android in virtual box instead of emulator. You're doing basically the same thing (running Android in a non real device) but it is faster and less risky to have issues. Give it a try: 
http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3YcSJJlxio

And if you use Xamarin, you can use Xamarin player:
https://xamarin.com/android-player

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem on Win7. The android emulator avd provided by Android Studio is very slow.
Try to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). In my opinion its the best android emulator avaiable to test your app on your computer. It's very fast and you get the response immediatly. 
It has a lot of options even Lollipop that I couldn't even dream to use in my computer on Avd provided by Android Studio.
And it's emulator is immediatly discovered by Android Studio when you try run your app.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same same message too but the emulator is running.
How about you try to update the HAX driver either by going to the intel website https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager or through the SDK Manager.

Comment: I believe Genymotion is the answer. Works like a charm, even-with API22, Lollipop.